# Misconception in applying Leibniz' rule

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

One can show using Leibniz' rule that 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n-1}{\ln x} dx = \ln|n+1|.$$
To be specific, if we set $g(n) := \int_0^1 \frac{x^n-1}{\ln x} dx$, then 
\begin{align}
g'(n) &= \frac d{dn} \int_0^1 \frac{x^n-1}{\ln x} dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \frac{x^n-1}{\ln x} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{x^n \ln x}{\ln x} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1x^n \, dx \\
&= \frac 1{n+1},
\end{align}
Upon integrating in $n$, we conclude that
$$
g(n) = \ln |n+1|+C.
$$
But we notice that $g(0)=0$, which implies that $C=0$. Hence,
$$
g(n)=\ln|n+1|.
$$

**Question.** 
If $g_a(n) := \int_0^1 \frac{x^n-a}{\ln x} \, dx$ for $a \not= 1$, then it seems like using Leibniz' rule would also give us $g_a(n) = \ln|n+1|$. But it cannot be, because $g_a(n)$ is a divergent integral. So the same justification using Leibniz' rule must not work for $f_a(n)$ somehow. But I'm not sure how. The hypothesis for Leiniz' rule is that $\frac{x^n-a}{\ln x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{x^n-a}{\ln x}$ both be continuous over $(0,1)$, which they are.

Comment: Leibniz's Rule has $f(x,t)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}$ are continuous on the closed interval over which the integral is effective.

Comment: In addition to Dr MV answer(+1), consider $n=2$ and $a=2$ and just graph. This is one of the many counter examples that show that the function is not cont. in the closed interval $[0,1]$, examine $x=1$. But I find this a brilliant question!

Comment: @imranfat Does the function $f$ have to be continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$? I'm not reading Leibniz's rule carefully, I guess. The asymptote at $x=1$ lies outside of the open interval $(0,1)$. Besides, if $a=1$, then the limit of $f$ as $x \to 1$ exists, but the function is still not continuous on $[0,1]$ because it is still undefined at $x=1$. This was what led me to "surmise" that the function needed only to be continuous over the open interval.

Comment: It has to be a closed interval as Dr MV stated, otherwise you will have a problem at the end point, see my example above.